# OPA test coverage schema?

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent

What is the schema of the JSON returned by a call to `opa test --coverage`? And is there a tool I can use to create a human-friendly coverage report?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any formal schema to the JSON output, but the struct that builds the coverage report per file can be found [here](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/opa/blob/main/cover/cover.go#L160).

The tools I'm aware of that can visualize the coverage are UI's like the [VS Code plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tsandall.opa), the [Rego Playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/) or [Styra DAS](https://www.styra.com/).

If you'd like to use other available tooling, you could probably write something similar to the [JUnit conversion script](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/contrib/tree/main/junit) found in the OPA contrib repo, but for the coverage report, and have that exported into some other coverage format.